# Jquery - Dropdown list maintain persistent selection

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a drop down list that when selected seems to revert to the default text, while the drop down works well and does what it is suppose to on the post back it as I said goes back to the default (sort by). I hope you awesome people could help me understand how I might be able to use Jquery to maintain the selected after a post back.

Here is the current code.

```
<select class="sorter" onchange="location=this.options[[this.selectedIndex]].value" style="float:right;margin-right:8px;">
<option value="">Sort by</option>
<option value="?orderby=0">Code</option>
<option value="?orderby=1">Title A-Z</option>
<option value="?orderby=2">Title Z-A</option>
<option value="?orderby=3">Manufacturer</option>
<option value="?orderby=4">Lowest price</option>
<option value="?orderby=5">Highest price</option>
<option value="?orderby=6">Lowest Quantity</option>
<option value="?orderby=7">Highest Quantity</option>
</select>
```

Comment: post back- means page refresh?

Comment: how the page post back?? is there any button click???

Comment: The state of HTML controls is not persisted accross requests. You would need to read the property from the querystring and set the value by hand, either server-side or client-side.

Comment: Again, why the postback?  You should be able to do anything you need to do with simple jQuery and AJAX.

Comment: If you are using aspx page then place drop down outside form runat="server". it will help you